# HTML5 FileSystem API: How to empty a file?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-filesystem

I modified the [Writing to a file](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-file-writing) example such that I can store some text from an input. I am storing the text `aaaaaaaaaa` to the file and afterwards the shorter `bbbbb` to the same file with the same function.

Additionally I am using the [Reading a file by name](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-file-readingbyname) example to read the file. I am getting -- with Chromium 15 -- this result:

```
bbbbbaaaaa
```

How can I reset the content of a file? The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/#idl-def-BlobBuilder) just offers getBlob() and append().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a ["truncate" method](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/#widl-FileWriter-truncate) on the FileWriter interface. (It works more like a "setFileSize" method, in that it's possible to "truncate" a file to a larger size than it already has.)

Comment: truncate did it. It took me half an hour not to run in an INVALID_STATE_ERR.

Comment: Yes it seems like it can't be called except immediately after opening the file, or something like that; the spec is not super clear.

Comment: Have a look on https://github.com/vitalets/bro-fs where `fs.writeFile()` truncates file automatically.

Comment: @vitalets that looks interesting, but it's for Node, and it's not clear whether this question was about server- or client-side work (though from 2011 it's more likely to be client-side). It's kind-of moot anyway since the HTML5 FileSystem API is defunct.

Comment: Nope. It's for browser, but with Node.js compatible API.

Comment: @vitalets oh oh, I see now. Right, thanks. (I'm kind-of surprised that Chrome still supports the FS API.)

Comment: AFAIK many extensions are using it so I think they will support it smoothly moving to new spec https://w3c.github.io/filesystem-api/