# Best way to write-over contents of file html5 filesystem api

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, fileapi, html5-filesystem

So I ran into an issue where I was writing contents to a file via the HTML5 File-system api. The issue occurs when new content is shorter than the previous content, the old content is written-over as expected, but the tail of the old contents remain at the end of the file. The data I am writing is meta data for a given web-app and tends to change periodically, but not very often, generally increasing in size but occasionally the meta data is smaller in size.

Example, original content of file `0000000000`, new content `11123` and after writing to the file, the contents become `1112300000`

To get around this, I have been removing the file and passing a callback to write the new information in on every call.  (`cnDAO.filesystem` is the filesystem object obtained when requesting persistent memory and has been initialized appropriately)

```
function writeToFile(fPath,data,callback){
  rmFile(fPath,function(){
      cnDAO.fileSystem.root.getFile(fPath, {
          create: true
      }, function(fileEntry) {
          fileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
              writer.onwriteend = function(e) {
                  callback();
              };
              writer.onerror = function(e3) {  };
              var blob = new Blob([data]);
              writer.write(blob);
          }, errorHandler);
      }, errorHandler);
  });    
}
function rmFile(fPath,callback){
  cnDAO.fileSystem.root.getFile(fPath, {
          create: true
      }, function(fileEntry) {
          fileEntry.remove(callback);
      }, errorHandler);
}
```

So, I was wondering if there was a better way to do what I am doing. `truncate` appeared in the following while I was searching for a solution ([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981525/html5-filesystem-api-how-to-empty-a-file)). As pointed out in the previous post truncate can only be called immediately after opening a file - Is truncate a better approach? Is what I'm doing better practice? Is there a quicker and easier way that I do not know about?

I would like to just start-fresh on every write to file- if that is plausible and/or good practice.